is there a better way to share common code across a set of python programs in a repository
I pick python when I want to do a number of different things quickly and easily - ie I always end up with a number of python "programs" - eg a set of scripts - or if I'm playing with something, a bunch of test programs etc - ie always a loose collection of lots of different programs.
however, there are certain things I'll share.   For instance, if I'm screwing around with AI - I might have 30 or so completely unrelated programs - but they'll all call out to an LLM.
Directory Structure
So the directory structure I always want in Git is like:
.
└── src/
    ├── common
    ├── program1
    ├── program2
    └── program3

Not wanted: explicit setup
but I haven't found any good way of making program1, program2, program3 reference common in a way that any ide or linter will understand it, straight out of git.  I know I can do things like set python paths etc - but I want someone to just be able to clone the library - change into program1 and run python program1.py and it just works - so anything that requires running/setting/configuring anything is just not an option to me.
Wanted: relative import
what I really want is for each program to just do:
     from ..common import some_helper

but when I try that I of course get
Error: attempted relative import with no known parent package

now... if I do this:
import sys
import os
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir)

most things actually work, but it's like 4 obscure lines I have to add to every python program - and some editors or linters don't find it.
these programs really have nothing to do with each other, beyond being part of the same repo, so any shared parentage would be pretty wrong.   They also usually have a bunch of other files, data files, readmes etc - so just putting everything in the same directory above common is too messy.
Alternative I tried: symlinks
The only really practical solution I've found so far is to just symlink the common directory into all the other directories - it's ugly - but it does work.
Question
Is there a better way - a more pythonic way?
I guess fundamentally - I want to know how to do a relative import without a known parent package?

You can make these folders their own modules by creating a __init__.py file. This should remove the error message

Any research you did and can share, e.g. Python Modules and Packages – An Introduction – Real Python ?

Maybe someone already asked about this import-error here on SO.

@oskar - I have init.py

@hc_dev - I've read all that - and there's lots of information about importing in the context of a package - but I've found nothing about relative imports when you don't have/don't want a package.

@DarrenOakey That's because relative imports are only valid within a package.   They are package relative, not path relative.

The easiest thing to do is to transform common in a proper package, and use an "editable install", so that any files edited in the folder are immediately visible to the projects in the other directories.
The way to do this is to create a minimal pyproject.toml file on the parent folder to your programs. As it is, a single "pyproject" file can define all your programs as packages, and they will all be importable directly:
Write this as the content of a pyproject.toml file, in your src folder:
[project]
name = "localproject"
version = "0.0.1"

[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["common", "program1", "program2", "program3"]

And then type pip install -e . in the shell - all of these programs should now be installed as packages in the active environment, and you can simply do import common.
Note that pyproject.toml will also allow for a \[project.scripts\] session that will automatically configure its entries as shell commands in the installed environment.
So,
[project]
...

[project.scripts]
command1 = "command1:main"

[tool.setuptools]
...

will make "command1" a shell command that will automatically run the command1/__init__.py file and call its  main function.
In addition to that, once the pyproject file is in place (and commited to the repo), instead of cloning the repository, those who would only use the tools can install the project directly with pip install git+https://<url>: this will install everything and let the commands, as specified in the [project.scripts] session automatically available.
All that said, if you want to follow your pre-thought gambiarra way, the modules inside program1, etc... you can add the parent (src) directory to the sys.path setting in Python.
Example, inside "program1/__init__.py", prior to other imports do:
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.insert(0, str(Path(__file__).parent.parent))



that's actually a great answer - and interesting - I didn't know about this editable install.    However - I really don't want someone to have to do anything for this to work. - and having to do a pip install -e is a problem.   Also - having to edit that file every time add another one also rules it out - it's easier to make the symlink each time :(.  But thank you - I will definitely find other uses for "editable install"

Note that by turning this into a Python project which installs packages, actually makes it EASIER for people to install. Instead of having to copy the directory tree into place (and manually updating it), everything people have to do is issue a single pip install command. Pip can fetch a tar.gz from the web or a git snapshot of the project all by itself.

Also, by adding a [scripts] session to the pyproject.toml file, upon pip install new shell commands are avaliable for the user at the CLI, which will automatically execute .py files and call entry-point functions therein: your users won´t even need to type "python command1" after chdiring into src: they will be able to just type "command1" in the shell prompt, anywhere.

TL;DR: A regular package (folder plus __init__) must pre-exist to be imported.
How to create a package and import siblings
Guided by section "Package Initialization" from Real Python tutorial Python Modules and Packages – An Introduction, let's assume you have this file-tree:
.
├── common
│   ├── common.py
│   ├── __init__.py
└── program1.py

With a Python package as folder common/ and package-initialization file __init__.py as required for regular packages.
Package initialization __init__.py
print(f'Invoking __init__.py for {__name__}')
from .common import *

Importing all (import *) defined objects from the relative sibling module (.common) defined by file common.py.
Module common.py
To take your example, the module only defines a function:
def some_helper():
    print("Hello from common!")

To be used in any program1.py
Since the package is initialized automatically by import common and provides all defined functions from the module, we can simply use it in any program1.py like:
from common import *

some_helper()

When run it prints the package-initialization and the desired greeting from our module:
Invoking __init__.py for common
Hello from common!

See also

What is __init__.py for? -- explaining the difference between namespace package and regular package.
Relative imports for the billionth time -- explaining that "Scripts can't import relative"


yeah - that works fine - but that's not the structure I am looking for:
program1.py is in a directory called program1.py
I think it really comes down to "scripts can't import relative" - and what I am asking, and what I want to do is "import relative from a script".
Anyway - I think the answer is... it can't be done - and I'll need to keep symlinking the directory in as I've been doing - which results in exactly the structure you define above.
thanks.
